# How to find 2 or more values in the same line from multiple registers

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing, command-line

I have a file with 128420 registers. However I need to find 2 values that are match in one or two or N lines.

I need to find values like 59708 and 27073 into the same line

Here is a example.

I have a file called `location_2020_01_10_11_12_17.dat`

Inside exist 3 registers

```
3G      COF9708 59708   334     020     28.219  100.9       0       NO TOP  8       U1900   BBBBB  8      AMV    27073   \N      \N      \N      \N      59708   \N      WCO3557 \N      \N      \N      \N      XXXXXXXX        4       TC  FALSE

3G      MXZ9708 59708   334     020     18.6841 997        0       NO TOP  8       U850    AAAAAA        36012   \N      \N      \N      \N      59708   \N      WMX9708 \N      \N      \N      \N       Sin_Municipio   XXXXXXXXXX        9       TX  FALSE 

2G      MX9708Z 59708   334     020     18.6841 996        0       NO TOP  Z       G850    AAAAAA        1227    \N      \N      \N      MX9708  59708   \N      \N      \N      \N      \N      \N       Sin_Municipio   YYYYYYYYYYY        9       MA  FALSE
```

I have used

```
grep -E -- '59708|27073' cell_location_2020_01_10_11_12_17.dat
```

also

```
egrep '59708|27073' cell_location_2020_01_10_11_12_17.dat
```

but doesnt work.

Could you please share any idea for show 1 result only

```
3G COF9708 59708 334 020 28.219 100.9 0 NO TOP 8 U1900 BBBBB 8 AMV 27073 \N \N \N \N 59708 \N WCO3557 \N \N \N \N XXXXXXXX 4 TC FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You want both strings matched but don't know their order?  Try

```
grep '59708.*27073\|27073.*59708' file
3G COF9708 59708 334 020 28.219 100.9 0 NO TOP 8 U1900 BBBBB 8 AMV 27073 \N \N \N \N 59708 \N WCO3557 \N \N \N \N XXXXXXXX 4 TC FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to include separators in the patterns, so that 59708 would not make a false match against 859708 or 597083.

You could use awk:

```
awk '/ 27073 / && / 59708 /' location_2020_01_10_11_12_17.dat
```